# Cannot install CVX

Tags: matlab, cvx

I try to install CVX in MATLAB but it still cannot complete. There are some error massages occurring during installation process. I have attached them already. Please see below

```
UNEXPECTED ERROR:     
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalid MEX-file
    'C:\Users\PAE\Downloads\Compressed\cvx-w64-tar\cvx\sdpt3\Solver\Mexfun\mexnnz.mexw64':
    C:\Users\PAE\Downloads\Compressed\cvx-w64-tar\cvx\sdpt3\Solver\Mexfun\mexnnz.mexw64
    is not a valid Win32 application.

.
Error in ==> checkdepconstr at 97
nnzmatold = mexnnz(AAt);
Error in ==> sqlpmain at 88
[At,b,y,indeprows,par.depconstr,feasible,par.AAt] = ...
Error in ==> sqlp at 241
[obj,X3,y,Z3,info,runhist] = ...
Error in ==> cvx_run_solver at 50
   [ varargout{1:nargout} ] = sfunc( inputs{:} );
Error in ==> cvx_sdpt3>solve at 362
[ obj, xx, y, zz, info ] = cvx_run_solver( @sqlp, blk, Avec, Cvec,
    b, OPTIONS, 'obj', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'info', settings, 5 ); %#ok
Error in ==> cvxprob.solve at 429
            [ x, status, tprec, iters ] = shim.solve( At, b, c,
                cones, quiet, prec, solv.settings, eargs{:} );
Error in ==> cvx_end at 88
        solve( prob );
Error in ==> cvx_setup at 213
        cvx_end

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please report this error to support, and include entire output of
CVX_SETUP in your support request.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try to find the solution for this problem in GOOGLE but I cannot find it.

Comment: Looks like your MATLAB is a 32-bit installation, trying to run a 64-bit MEX file.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using windows7 (64bit) and my MATLAB version is 7.9 (64bit). This MATLAB folder is in "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b". So I think my MATLAB was installed correctly as 64 bit version.

Comment: Are you sure? (If so the error "is not a valid Win32 application" makes no sense). What does running `mexext` at the command line return?

Comment: Please double-check by running `computer` from the MATLAB prompt

Comment: Another possible problem: The MEX file might depend on other DLLs that it can't find, or are themselves for the wrong architecture.  The free tool "Dependency Walker" might help you track this down.  When using this tool, be sure to manually add the paths for the MATLAB DLLs.